# Simple PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

My webpage looks like this

```
<h3>Headline</h3>

      Unimportant Nov 20, 2012<br />
```

And I just want to get the date and format it for new DateTime...Is it possible? Thank you for any kind of advice.

Comment: If its your website, why do you have to get the date out of the output?

Comment: Because it's static website and I have to parse a content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([A-Za-z]{3} [012]\d, [12](\d){3})
```

Should do the trick. This will catch any date with the format you provided.

Comment: you could replace `2(\d){3}` with `[12](\d){3}`... just in case ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've adjusted the regex to that.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'll buy you a beer.